# Setting Timeout Value for LDAP authentication at Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, timeout, spring-ldap

I use Spring LDAP authentication via:

```
auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .userSearchFilter("userPrincipalName={0}")
            .contextSource()
            .managerDn(ldapAuthenticationConfig.getManagerDn())
            .managerPassword(ldapAuthenticationConfig.getManagerPassword())
            .url(ldapAuthenticationConfig.getUrl());
```

However, it takes too much time at login page when LDAP server is unavailable. I want to learn whether I can login or not within a considerable time.

Here is the dependency that I use:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

How can I set a timeout value for LDAP authentication at Spring Boot?

Answer (score 10):

I also encountered this problem, and found several answers pointing out the `com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout` environment variable, but could not find how to add to Spring Security with Java Config.

To accomplish it, first extract the creation of the context source:

```
@Autowired
private DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource context;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder
                .ldapAuthentication()
                .userSearchFilter(LDAP_USER_SEARCH_FILTER)
                .contextSource(context);
}
```

Then, when creating the context source (I did it in the same confiuration class, without builder), you can specify environment properties, and you can add there the timeout attribute:

```
@Bean
public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource createContext() {
    DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(LDAP_SERVER);
    contextSource.setUserDn(LDAP_MANAGER_DN);
    contextSource.setPassword(LDAP_MANAGER_PASSWORD);

    Map<String, Object> environment = new HashMap<>();
    environment.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout", LDAP_TIMEOUT);
    contextSource.setBaseEnvironmentProperties(environment);
    return contextSource;
}
```

Note that uppercase LDAP_ variables are all constants in my config class.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

for those who use .yml or .properties file

```
  ldap:
    urls: LDAP://[YOUR FAKE DOMAIN OR IP]
    base: dc=fakedomain,dc=com
    username: [AD_USER_NAME]
    password: [AD_USER_PASSWORD]
    base-environment:
      com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout: 500
```

I put `com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout: 500` in `spring.ldap.base-enviroment`

Note: I use spring

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```